# How to solve the Diffusion PDE with Fourier Series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I need to solve the diffusion equation using a Fourier Series. The PDE is

$$ \frac{\partial \rho (x,t)}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial ^2 \rho (x,t)}{\partial x^2} $$

The initial and boundary conditions are the following

$$ \rho (0,t)=\rho (L_x,t) = 0 $$
$$ \rho (x,0) = A e^{ - \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{l}} $$

where $D, L_x, A, x_0$ and $l$ are given constants.

I need help to see if what I did to solve it is correct. I separated the equation: $\rho(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, then divided the equation by $DX(x)T(t)$ and finally made it equal to $-k^2$.

After applying the boundary conditions and the initial condition, I got the following Fourier Series:

$$ \rho (x,t) =A \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin {\left(\frac{n\pi}{L_x}x \right)}\exp{\left( -D \left(\frac{n\pi}{L_x} \right)^2 t - \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{l} \right)} $$

Now, I honestly don't know how to get an expression for the $a_n$. I think I have to integrate it from $0$ to $L$ but this seems more complicated than what it should be so I need to make sure that I have the Fourier Series correct.

Comment: Generally at this point you will use the initial condition. Take the ρ(x,t) you found when t=0 and equate it to the given ρ(x,0). Then you should get something simpler to integrate

Comment: @Pat I did use it, I now edited and clarified the question.

Comment: The initial condition won't appear inside of the series directly, it appears in the integral for the $a_n$. In the series itself you should just have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(n\pi x/L_x) \exp(-D(n\pi/L_x)^2 t)$ (which does seem correct at a glance). That being said, the $a_n$ here can only be written down in terms of the error function.

Comment: Following on from what Ian said, you should then find $$e^{\frac{-(x-x_{0})^{2}}{l}}=\rho(x,0)=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L_{x}}\right)$$ To get the coefficients, multiply both sides by $\sin \left(\frac{m\pi x}{L_{x}}\right)$ and integrate over the domain of $x$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{L}e^{\frac{-(x-x_{0})^{2}}{l}}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L_{x}}\right)dx&=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{n}\int_{0}^{L}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L_{x}}\right)\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L_{x}}\right)\\&=\begin{cases} \frac{La_{m}}{2}&\text{if $n=m\ne 0$}\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}\end{align} Then solve for $a_{m}$.